# SBT git dependency produces error if scalaVersions different

Tags: git, scala, sbt, playframework-2.0

So I'm using Play 2 in Scala, setting up some dependencies, and I think I'm tickling a bug in SBT.  Anybody else seen anything like this?

I try to add [knockoff](https://github.com/tristanjuricek/knockoff) in Build.scala [as directed,](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Full-Configuration) thus:

```
val knockoff = RootProject(uri("git://github.com/tristanjuricek/knockoff.git"))

val main =
    PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA)
    .dependsOn(knockoff)
```

and then run it.  For some reason, it goes looking for source and javadoc jars.  (Why?)

```
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] com.tristanhunt#knockoff_2.9.1;0.8.0-16!knockoff_2.9.1.jar(src) (88ms)
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/tristanhunt/knockoff_2.9.1/0.8.0-16/knockoff_2.9.1-0.8.0-16-sources.jar
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] com.tristanhunt#knockoff_2.9.1;0.8.0-16!knockoff_2.9.1.jar(doc) (86ms)
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/tristanhunt/knockoff_2.9.1/0.8.0-16/knockoff_2.9.1-0.8.0-16-javadoc.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.tristanhunt#knockoff_2.9.1;0.8.0-16!knockoff_2.9.1.jar(src)
[warn]  :: com.tristanhunt#knockoff_2.9.1;0.8.0-16!knockoff_2.9.1.jar(doc)
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

These missing jars shouldn't be fatal, but they are:

```
[error] {file:/home/joel/TEST2/bar/}bar/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: download failed: com.tristanhunt#knockoff_2.9.1;0.8.0-16!knockoff_2.9.1.jar(src)
[error] download failed: com.tristanhunt#knockoff_2.9.1;0.8.0-16!knockoff_2.9.1.jar(doc)
[error] java.util.NoSuchElementException: Either.right.value on Left
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

Here's some of the stack trace:

```
[error] download failed: com.tristanhunt#knockoff_2.9.1;0.8.0-16!knockoff_2.9.1.jar(doc)
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Either.right.value on Left
at scala.Either$RightProjection.get(Either.scala:229)
at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$56.apply(PlayCommands.scala:606)
at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$56.apply(PlayCommands.scala:593)
at sbt.Command$$anonfun$sbt$Command$$apply1$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Command.scala:74)
at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:92)
```

Other projects as dependencies work fine, but not this one.

Comment: Take a look at SBT classifiers to only depend on release jars and not source or javadoc. See this: https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Library-Management

Comment: A standard (non-Play) sbt project with that dependency doesn't show this error on 'update'.  From the stack trace (thanks for posting it), it looks like the trouble is from PlayCommands, which does not come from sbt (despite the package name).

Comment: Good idea, I tried setting up a minimal sbt project to see if I could duplicate your result, but I'm seeing the same thing.  You can see the project [here](https://github.com/truher/sbt-dependency-test); it's just the "hello" project from the sbt doc, with this one RootProject dependency added.  I pasted the console output into the README.  What do you think?

Comment: @Brian, the library dependency isn't quite what I want, I really want a subproject, because I'm planning to fork it and mess with it a little.  I couldn't figure out how to apply the library-management ideas to a subproject, though.  Is there an example of that somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ugh.  Sorry for wasting your time, Interwebs.

The problem was that the "parent" and "child" projects specified different scalaVersions.

The parent was 2.9.1, child 2.9.2.  Changing either one to be the same as the other fixes this problem.

Comment: I believe there are two potentially useful issues to follow up on here, however.  First, play should not die with such an unhelpful message (it is calling right.value when it should not).  Second, I believe sbt should provide a better error message or even not error at all and perhaps give a warning.  For the second, please open a bug with sbt.

Comment: @joeltruher actually, you've saved a lot of time for me ;)

Comment: I add my bit of salt here, just doing a `play clean-all` solved the problem!